# Merge [pytesseract] with [python-tesseract]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

To the best of my knowledge the tags  [pytesseract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pytesseract) and [python-tesseract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-tesseract) refer to the same PyPI package: https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/ The package description calls it "python-tesseract" but the package is imported as `pytesseract`.

Note that this is not the same as [tesserocr](https://pypi.org/project/tesserocr/) or any version of "pytesser".

Comment: Why?! Messing with the stones can cause time to split into different branches!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag wiki of [pytesseract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pytesseract) (x 177), makes it clear that it is referring to Python Tesseract:

> Python-tesseract is a wrapper for Google's Tesseract-OCR Engine. It can recognize the text available in images.

Given that [the package description](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) mentions it as Python-Tesseract, as well as the fact that [python-tesseract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-tesseract) (x 324) is used more than the other tag, it does make more sense to have that as the master tag. Another slightly related note is that [python-tesseract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-tesseract) is sponsored, whereas [pytesseract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pytesseract) is not.

I've added [pytesseract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pytesseract) as a synonym for [python-tesseract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-tesseract)